# Necesito sumar el rango de una array de números, pero con determinado punto de partida

Tags: javascript

como ven estoy ejecutando un for para que sume todo los números de un array, eso le entiendo perfectamente ya que la función seria esta :

```
var suma = 0;
  for(var i = 0;  array.length > i < array.length ; i++) {
    suma = suma + array[i]}

    console.log (suma);
```

como verán eso lo entiendo pero añadieron una dificultad y me estan pidiendo sumar números pero en un determinado rango dentro del array, para interpretar esto se que debe haber ya establecido un numero inicial y uno final dentro de la array (supongo que esto se hace en ejemplo cuando tienes un carrito de compras  y necesitas solo encontrar la suma de artículos seleccionado dentro de la suma del total), para desarrollar esto tengo claro que debo iterar con un for entre esos rangos.

la pregunta es esta.

```
function sumaTodos(array) {
  // La funcion llamada 'sumaTodos' recibe como argumento un array con dos numeros
  // y debe devolver la suma total entre todos los numeros dentro de ese rango
  // ej:
  // sumaTodos([1,3]) => 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
  // Nota: Los numeros estan ordenados de menor a mayor.

  // Tu código aca:
```

Por entendido esta claro que debo efectuar un ciclo for que sume los elementos del array, pero necesito entonces primero entiendoq ue debo calcular el menor para saber mi punto de partida

```
var menor = Infinity;
var puntoinciial =[]

for (var i = 0; i< array.length; i++){ 
 if (array[i] < menor){
 menor = array[i];
 puntoinciial[0] =menor;
  
 }
```

Después debo tomar ese punto incial y sumar todo lo que siga hasta el ultimo elemento de la lista.

coloque este codigo donde dentro del ciclo for coloque punto de partida el punto inicial osea el mínimo del array, aunque creo que podria hacer `i=menor` directamente. y me queda un codigo como este:

```
var suma = 0;
  for(var i = menor;  i < array.length ; i++) {
    suma = suma + array[i];
  }
    

    return  suma ;
```

Y bueno ya intente 3 horas, no me dio, si se sumar determinados puntos de un array, pero todo una cadena de numeros con rango  no pude, esto fue lo que hice lamente si alguno piensa que es muy facil, pero no tengo a mas donde poder preguntar, agradezco una mano.

```
function sumaTodos(array) {
  // La funcion llamada 'sumaTodos' recibe como argumento un array con dos numeros
  // y debe devolver la suma total entre todos los numeros dentro de ese rango
  // ej:
  // sumaTodos([1,3]) => 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
  // Nota: Los numeros estan ordenados de menor a mayor.

  // Tu código aca: 
var menor = Infinity;

for (var i = 0; i< array.length; i++){ 
 if (array[i] < menor){
   menor = array[i];  
 }
}

var suma = 0;
  for(var i = menor;  i < array.length -1  ; i++) {
    suma = suma + array[i];
  }

    return  suma ;
}
```

Comment: Yo diría que, hasta llegar a la frase `Y bueno ya intente 3 horas, ...`, es todo **ruido** que solo distrae, sin afectar para nada a la pregunta. Creo que deberías consultar [¿ Como elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El `array` que recibe la función como parámetro no es para que lo iteres, solamente es para que extraigas el valor `array[0]` y `array[1]` para obtener el inicio y el fin del `for` que tienes que iterar para sacar cada número comprendido entre ambos valores.

```js
let numeros = [1, 3]

console.log(suma_todos(numeros));

function suma_todos (numeros) {
  let inicio = numeros[0];
  let fin = numeros[1];
  let suma = 0;
  
  for (let i = inicio; i <= fin; i++) {
    suma += i;
  }
  
  return suma;
}
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho, pude resolverlo. Todo muchas gracias y les deseo muchos éxitos.